# How to print out equation that multiple linear regression model is using in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, linear-regression

For a multiple linear regression model in Tensorflow in python, how can you print out the equation that the model is using to predict the label. The model I am currently using takes two features to predict one label, so I think the general equation is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYqMm.png) but how could I get the unknown parameters and values of all the constants using Tensorflow?

Code:

```
fundingFeatures = fundingTrainSet.copy()
fundingLabels = fundingFeatures.pop('% of total funding spent')
fundingFeatures = np.array(fundingFeatures)
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(fundingFeatures)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    normalizer,
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])
model.compile(loss = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                      optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.06, momentum=0.0, nesterov=True, name="SGD",
))
model.fit(fundingFeatures, fundingLabels, epochs=1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain how you can write the equation of your NN.

In order to do that, I have modified your code and added fixed values for your Y features and Y labels. I'm doing that in order to show the whole calculation step by step so that next time you can do it yourself.

Based on all the information you have provided, it seems that you have

1. NN with 2 layers.
2. First layer is a Normatization layer
3. Second layer is a Dense layer
4. You have 2 features in your input tensor and 1 single output

Let's start with the normalization layer. For normalization layers, it is kind "strange" in my opinion to use the term "weight". The weights are basically
the mean and variance which will be applied to each input in order to normalize the data.

I wil call the 2 input features x0 and x1

if you run my code (which is your code with my fixed data), you will see that the weights for the normalization layer are

[5.  4.6]
[ 5.4  11.24]

It means that the means for your [x0 x1] columns are [5.  4.6] and the variances are [5.4  11.24]

Can we verify that? Yes, we can. Let's check for x0.

```
[1,4,8,7,3,6,6,5,2,8,5]
mean = 5
stddev = 2.323790008
variance = 5.4 ( variance = stddev^2)
```

As you can see, it matches the "weights" of the normalization layer.

As data is pushed thru the normalization layer, each value will be normalized based on
x' = (x-mean)/stddev  ( stddev, not variance )

You can check that by applying the normalization to the data.
In the code, if you run this 2 lines

```
normalized_data = normalizer(fundingFeatures)

print(normalized_data)
```

You will get

```
[[-1.7213259   1.31241   ]
 [-0.43033147  1.014135  ]
 [ 1.2909944   0.41758505]
 [ 0.86066294 -0.47723997]
 [-0.86066294 -1.07379   ]
 [ 0.43033147  1.31241   ]
 [ 0.43033147 -1.07379   ]
 [ 0.         -1.07379   ]
 [-1.2909944   0.71586   ]
 [ 1.2909944  -1.07379   ]]
```

Let's verify the first number.

```
x0[0] = 1
x0'[0] = (1-5)/2.323790008 = -1.7213 ( it does match)
```

At this point, we should be able to write the equations for the normalization layer

```
y[0]' = (x0-5)/2.323790008   # (x-mean)/stddev
y[1]' = (x1-4.6)/3.352610923
```

Now, these 2 outputs will be inject in the next layer. Remember, you have a Dense layer and therefore it is fully connected. It means that both values will be inject in the single neuron.

These lines show the value of both weights and bias for the Dense layer.

```
weights = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]

print(weights)
print(biases)


[[-0.12915221]
 [-0.41322172]]
[0.32663438]
```

A neuron multiplies each input by a given weight, adds all results with the bias.
Let's modify y[0]' and y[1]' to include the weights.

```
y[0]' = (x0-5)/2.323790008)* -0.12915221
y[1]' = (x1-4.6)/3.352610923 * -0.41322172
```

We are close, we just need to sum up these 2 and add the bias

```
y' = ((x0-5)/2.323790008)* -0.12915221 + (x1-4.6)/3.352610923 * -0.41322172 + 0.32663438
```

Since you don't have an activation function, we can stop here.

How can we verify if the formula is right?
Let's use the model to predict the label for a random input and see if it matches the result we get when we put the same values in our equation.

First, let's run a model prediction for [4,5]

```
print(model.predict( [[4,5]] )) 
[[0.3329112]]
```

Now, let's plug the same inputs to our equation

y' = (((4-5)/2.323790008)* -0.12915221) + ((5-4.6)/3.352610923 * -0.41322172) + 0.32663438

y' = 0.332911

It seems that we are good. I cut some precisions just be make my life easier.

Here is the function for your model. Just replace my numbers with your numbers.

y' = ((x0-5)/2.323790008)* -0.12915221 + (x1-4.6)/3.352610923 * -0.41322172 + 0.32663438

And here is the code. I have also added tensorboard so you can verify yourself what I have said here.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime


fundingFeatures = tf.constant([[1, 9], [4, 8], [8, 6], [7 ,3], [3 ,1], [6, 9], [6, 1], [5, 1], [2, 7], [8, 1]], dtype=tf.int32)
fundingLabels = tf.constant([ 0.8160469,  -0.05249139,  1.1515405,   1.0792135,   0.80369186, -1.7353221,  1.0092108,   0.19228514, -0.10366996,  0.10583907])
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(fundingFeatures)

normalized_data = normalizer(fundingFeatures)

print(normalized_data)

print("Features mean raw: %.2f" % (fundingFeatures[:,0].numpy().mean()))
print("Features std raw: %.2f" % (fundingFeatures[:,0].numpy().std()))
print("Features mean raw: %.2f" % (fundingFeatures[:,1].numpy().mean()))
print("Features std raw: %.2f" % (fundingFeatures[:,1].numpy().std()))

print("Features mean: %.2f" % (normalized_data.numpy().mean()))
print("Features std: %.2f" % (normalized_data.numpy().std()))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    normalizer,
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])
model.compile(loss = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                      optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.06, momentum=0.0, nesterov=True, name="SGD",
))


log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.summary()
print('--------------')
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
print('--------------')


model.fit(fundingFeatures, fundingLabels, epochs=1000, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]

print(weights)
print(biases)

print ("\n")

weights = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]

print(weights)
print(biases)

print('\n--------- Prediction ------')

print(model.predict( [[4,5]] ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But when I printed out the weights and biases I got the following outputted:

Comment: Weights: [ 8.89 11.5 ]
Biases: [321.69 357.53]

Comment: How would I convert this into an equation for multiple linear regression

Comment: Well, that seems right. Those are the 2 weights and biases of your model. Without the code, I don't know the architecture of your model and therefore I can't write the equation.

Comment: Just added the code, and thank you for bearing with me :)

Comment: Use these instead if possible:                                                                                 
                                                                                                                               
weights for normalizer layer: [ 8.89 11.5 ]
biases for normalizer layer: [321.69 357.53]

(not even sure if the normalizer biases and weights matter as it is part of preprocessing)

weights for Dense layer: [[ 0.08] [19.3 ]]

biases for Dense layer: [11.54]

Comment: I have updated my answer with the explanation. You can just follow what I have describe and plug your values there. If you find the answer helpful, don't forget to accept it

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this will definitely help and I greatly appreciate you bearing with me!

Comment: Just checked as well and have gotten a final equation which is just 0.001 off so that is great! Also, just out of curiosity, when you said you cut some precisions to make life easier, would you mind sharing what these might be?

Comment: it can't recall. it was just while typing here or in excel to verify the number i did not type more than a few decimal places