# Multiple Linear Regression with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, linear-regression

I'm trying to perform a Multiple Linear Regression with TensorFlow and confront the results with `statsmodels` library.

I generated two random variables `X1` and `X2` (so that anyone can reproduce it) that will explain the Y variable. The `X2` variable is completely useless for this regression, it's just noise with a big scale so that the coefficient will result not significant (p-val close to 1).
At the end I should obtain a model that is basically. `y_data = alpha + (0.25)x1 + (0.00)x2 + error.`

I tried to adapt this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471590/how-to-print-out-equation-that-multiple-linear-regression-model-is-using-in-tens) to my randomly generated data, but unfortunately, this is not working at all.
This below is my try:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from tensorflow import keras
import datetime


#generating variables:
np.random.seed(1)
lin_x = np.arange(0,200,2)
y_data = np.true_divide(lin_x,4)
n = np.shape(lin_x)
##adding noise:
rand1 = norm.rvs(loc=0,scale=5,size=n)
np.random.seed(2)
rand2 = norm.rvs(loc=0,scale=1000,size=n)
x1 = np.add(lin_x,rand1)
x2 = rand2

#creating the X matrix: beta = (X'X)^-1(X'y):
x_data = np.column_stack((x1,x2))
#adding ones vector for the intercept:
x_data = sm.add_constant(x_data)

#MLR with statsmodels:
mod = sm.OLS(y_data,x_data)
LinReg = mod.fit()
print(LinReg.summary())



#MLR with tensorflow:
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(x_data)

normalized_data = normalizer(x_data)

print(normalized_data)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  normalizer,
  layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(loss = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
                learning_rate=0.06, momentum=0.0, nesterov=True, name="SGD",
              ))

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.summary()
print('--------------')
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
print('--------------')

x_data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_data)
y_data_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_data)
model.fit(y_data_tf,x_data_tf, epochs=1000, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]

print("TensorFlow results: ")
print("weigths: ", weights)
print("biases: ", biases)

print(LinReg.summary())
```

How can I get the same coefficients that I've obtained with the `statsmodels` library using TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issues with your code are the following:

1. While it is necessary to add a column of ones to the features matrix `x_data` before running the regression with statsmodels, this is not necessary when running the regression with tensorflow. This means that you are passing 3 features to tensorflow instead of 2, where the additional feature (the first column of `x_data`) is constant.
2. You are normalizing `x_data` after the first column of ones has already been added with `x_data = sm.add_constant(x_data)`. As a column of ones has zero variance, after normalization you get a column of `nan` (as you are dividing by zero). This means that the first of the 3 features that you are passing to tensorflow is completely missing (i.e. it's always `nan`).
3. While statsmodels takes as inputs at first `y` and then `X`, tensorflow takes as inputs at first `X` and then `y`. This means that you have switched the features and target when running the regression in tensorflow.

I included a complete example below.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(0)

N = 500    # number of samples
K = 2      # number of features

# generate the features
m = np.array([0, 0])     # means
s = np.array([5, 1000])  # variances
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(m * np.ones(K), s * np.eye(K), N)

# generate the target
b = 0.5                   # bias
w = np.array([0.107, 0])  # weights
y = b + np.dot(X, w) + np.random.normal(0, 1, N)

# normalize the features
X = (X - np.mean(X, axis=0)) / np.std(X, axis=0, ddof=1)

# run a linear regression with statsmodels
reg = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(X)).fit()

# run a linear regression with tensorflow
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01))
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

bias = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].flatten()

# compare the parameters
print('Statsmodels parameters:')
print(np.round(reg.params, 3))
# [0.523 0.25 0.063]

print('Tensorflow parameters:')
print(np.round(np.append(bias, weights), 3))
# [0.528 0.25 0.066]
```

Comment: the code works but, the output should be that "beta1" (the coefficient of x1) is 0.25. In your example and how you generated the multivariate gaussian x1 variables are 10 times smaller than the y data, so I'm getting a "beta1" = 11 (approx). But the slope should be y = 1/4X1... I'm trying to fix this right now but unsuccessfully for now..  I thought that the bias was the slope cause it has a value of 0.25 (that is the value of beta1 I would like to have). Can you fix this little issue?

Comment: I'm not understanding how you are generating the variables. So I thought this data with a relation of y=(0.25)x1. Why you've setted the first weight equal to 0.107? Since with OLS you can train the model also without normalizing the data this to me is less confusing. Is the normalization of the features always necessary if I use SGD? Because in this way I will always get the estimates of the normalized data. Just want to know if I can train a model without normalization. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Flavia I changed the optimizer choosing Adam and it's working also without the normalization process